# Synchronized JPA relationships

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need a way to have an object that is in sync with its relation entities.
Say for example, I have a Post and Comment entities

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "posts")
    @Data
    public class Post{
        @Id
        private Long id;
        
        private String title;
        
        private String content
        
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "comments")
    @Data
    public class Comment{
        @Id
        private Long id;
        
        private String content;
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Post post;  
    }
```

Say the post had 4 comments. And had an object in a PostsService with the Post and printed the number of coments, it prints 4. But when I delete 2 comments in the same method and print the number of comments, it still prints 4.

HOW CAN I HAVE A SYNCHRONIZED OBJECT SUCH THAT IF I DELETE THE COMMENTS THE POST OBJECT ALSO GETS THE CHANGES.

```
// Post service class
public void someMethod()
{
    Post post = postRepository.findById(1);
    System.out.println(  post.comments.size() ); // Prints 4
    
    // CODE TO DELETE TWO COMMENTS
    
    System.out.println(  post.comments.size() ); // Still Prints 4
}
```

Comment: First, fix the mapping of yor bidirectional association. It's incorrect. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional. Then use orpganRemoval=true on the OneToMany, and simply use `post.comments.remove(comment)` to remove (and thus delete) a comment from a post. A removeComment() method in Post would be cleaner. You should really avoid eager loading on OneToMany associations. It's the simplest way to ruin your application performance.

Comment: Also note that your question has nothing to do with Spring Boot

Comment: @Turing85  I am looking for a way where I don't have to refetch from the db everytime there are changes in the relationship entities

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `// CODE TO DELETE TWO COMMENTS`

Comment: @Mafor ` commentsRepository.deleteById(1)`

Comment: @gitau to be clear: it's not "an article". It's the official Hibernate documentation. The place where you should go as soon as you have a question about Hibernate. Linked from the home page of the Hibernate project. The thing you should read before using it.